# New Blend File has A LOT of orphan data

Tags: blend-files, data-blocks, startup-file

Everytime i start a new blend file, i have orphan data.  3 materials that won't go away 99 meshes, and 99 objects.
Tried purging them and resaving the startup default. But they come back everytime.
How to i clean these once and for all.
On the latest build 2.93.

Thank you
Gary

Answer (score 1):

There is *File* -> *Defaults* -> *Load Factory Settings*, but this is what usually works for me.

1. Purge data.
2. Save the file and close Blender.
3. Reopen the file you just saved.
4. Immediately save it and close Blender again.

Now the data blocks should be gone and you can open it and set it as your default startup file.

If there is still some data hanging around for some reason, you can switch your Outliner to the Blender File display mode and delete the data blocks manually.

[image]

Some things don't seem to be properly marked for deletion, it's never been clear to me why.

Comment: Tried this...everytime time the objects and materials reappear. Its always 99 object, 99 meshes, and 2 materials.

Comment: That is weird.  My initial thought is that your OS isn't allowing write access to the file for some reason?  (Assuming Windows) You can find your default file in %appdata%, might be worth looking at it and seeing if anything funky is going on in Windows.

Comment: Its writing correctly. Save anything i do the a new startup file. But always adds the objects/meshes and materials. Tried factory reset....the were still there.